# Using encore webpack with symfony project

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using the Encore/Webpack in my Symfony project, but Im having troubles with the installation.

I'm following the official guide: [Link to official guide](http://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/simple-example.html)

My project folder:

```
projectname
---/app
---/assets
       /css
           /global.scss
       /js
           /main.js
...
---/node_modules
       /.bin
           /encore
...
---/web
      /build
etc
```

I was following

> Create a new file called webpack.config.js at the root of your
>   project.

It looks like:

```
projectname
    ...
    webpack.config.js
```

I filled it with the example code. Afterwards I wanted to 'build' the assets with the command `encore dev` on path: `projectname\node_modules\.bin`

When I do this, I get the following error code:

```
Running webpack ...

No configuration file found and no output filename configured via CLI option.
A configuration file could be named 'webpack.config.js' in the current directory.
Use --help to display the CLI options.
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. When I move the webpack.config.js to the .bin folder.. that part works, but than the build doesn't work, because it wants to install the files into .../.bin/build/ which is not correct. I want it into projectname/build like the example.

Comment: When executing the encore command your current working directory should be `projectname` (or where the `webpack.config.js` is). Also make sure your user has the correct permissions to that file (if this applies to your issue). So, your command should probably be `cd projectname && ./node_modules/bin/encore-dev`.

Comment: When I'm the working directory where my webpack file is stored and do `./node_modules/bin/encore dev` I recieve the error: `'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`     I'm working on a machine windows.. maybe that might be the case?

Comment: On Windows you need to use "\" instead of `/`. Your command should probably be `.\node_modules\bin\encore-dev` :)

Comment: Thanks, I feel stupid for missing that one.

Comment: No worries. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

try this commend it's work for me
install webpack-notifier@^1.6.0 --save-dev